# Right move multiple columns if another column's value are NaNs in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to move `price`, `quantity` columns by one place on right side, if `volume`'s row values are `NaN`:

```
                  date          price  quantity   volume
0  2015/01/28 10:00:00              0      5820      NaN
1  2020/02/27 11:10:44  3,164,886.76          0   8338.0
2  2018/07/19 10:27:32    16,220,000          0   9229.0
3  2019/11/02 10:29:49     2,847,767          0   8321.0
4  2018/03/18 10:00:00     1,194,656          0   9824.0
5  2018/11/17 10:00:00              0      5108      NaN
6  2017/12/26 10:20:44     2,909,552          0  11153.0
7  2019/02/17 10:47:35              0      7341      NaN
8  2019/09/26 10:11:07     3,539,472          0   8086.0
9  2017/04/10 10:00:00     3,066,040          0  10682.0
```

I have filtered the subset of dataframe by `df[df['volume'].isnull()]`

```
                  date price  quantity  volume
0  2015/01/28 10:00:00     0      5820     NaN
5  2018/11/17 10:00:00     0      5108     NaN
7  2019/02/17 10:47:35     0      7341     NaN
```

Just wonder how could I get an output like this, thank you.

```
                  date          price  quantity  volume
0  2015/01/28 10:00:00            NaN         0    5820
1  2020/02/27 11:10:44  3,164,886.76          0    8338
2  2018/07/19 10:27:32    16,220,000          0    9229
3  2019/11/02 10:29:49     2,847,767          0    8321
4  2018/03/18 10:00:00     1,194,656          0    9824
5  2018/11/17 10:00:00            NaN         0    5108
6  2017/12/26 10:20:44     2,909,552          0   11153
7  2019/02/17 10:47:35            NaN         0    7341
8  2019/09/26 10:11:07     3,539,472          0    8086
9  2017/04/10 10:00:00     3,066,040          0   10682
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ffill`:

```
s = df["volume"].isnull()
df.loc[s] = df.loc[s].ffill(1)
df.loc[s,"quantity"] = 0 #or df.loc[s,"price"] if you want to move price
print (df)

                  date         price quantity volume
0  2015/01/28 10:00:00             0        0   5820
1  2020/02/27 11:10:44  3,164,886.76        0   8338
2  2018/07/19 10:27:32    16,220,000        0   9229
3  2019/11/02 10:29:49     2,847,767        0   8321
4  2018/03/18 10:00:00     1,194,656        0   9824
5  2018/11/17 10:00:00             0        0   5108
6  2017/12/26 10:20:44     2,909,552        0  11153
7  2019/02/17 10:47:35             0        0   7341
8  2019/09/26 10:11:07     3,539,472        0   8086
9  2017/04/10 10:00:00     3,066,040        0  10682
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to move columns one by one, right?

Comment: I believe so @ahbon.

Comment: Instead of `price`, `quantity` need to right move, if we have more columns say `price`, `quantity`, `name`, `address` to move if `volume`'s row values are `NaN`s, what should I modify in your code?

Comment: You can keep on adding `df.loc[s,"address"] = df.loc[s,"name"]`... I am not familiar with a way to do all in one go with `loc`.

Comment: for moving multiple columns,  it doesn't make sense to keep adding `.loc` assigment to the code for each moved column. You should use `shift` instead

Comment: @AndyL. It was the first idea that came into my mind to use `shift`, but by testing it I only got `NaN`s when I do something as simple as `df.shift(axis="columns")`, so I left it out.

Comment: `shift`  works fine as long as you handle columns dtypes appropriately.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html